# Refresh a filter onEdit() in Google sheets when number is less than x

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that we use as a cash log which is updated daily.

I want to limit the amount of rows that are visible to the person entering data. To that end I added a column (#12/L in this case) which applies the number 1 to each new row of data, and sequentially increases the existing rows.

I have a filter applied to Column L that limits viewing to rows that are less than or equal to 5. This accomplishes what I want, but I have to click Filter/Ok to update the view when new rows are added.

Is there a way I could create an onEdit script to monitor Column L for changes, and reapply a filter when a change happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal as follows.

- The Spreadsheet has the basic filter at the column "L".
- When the value of the column "L" is updated, you want to refresh the filter. For this, you want to use OnEdit trigger.    - This is from your question of `Is there a way I could create an onEdit script to monitor Column L for changes, and reapply a filter when a change happens?`.

In this case, how about copying the existing basic filter of column "L" and removing it, and creating the copied filter again? I thought that by this flow, your goal might be able to be achieved. When this flow is reflected to the Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, when you want to run this script, **please manually edit the cell of the column "L" on the sheet of "Sheet1"**. By this, the script is run. The script copies the existing basic filter of the column "L" and remove it, and create it as new filter. By this, the filter can be reflected to the new value.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 12) return;
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  const fRange = filter.getRange();
  const criterion = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(12).copy();
  filter.remove();
  fRange.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(12, criterion);
}
```

#### Note:

- This script is run by the OnEdit trigger. So when you directly run the script with the script editor, an error occurs. Please be careful this.
- When the cell of the column "L" is updated by a script, in that case, I would like to recommend to include above method to the script. Because when the cell is updated by a script, the OnEdit trigger is not fired.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Thank you so much for your response. I'm definitely filing this one away for future use. I do realize that I was a little fast-and-loose with the word filter. Rather than a filter created as a result of a formula, I need to refresh a Filter View, i.e. one created by selecting the funnel and setting up a Filter by condition... An example of what I have can be viewed here: (docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…) Essentially nothing above the #5 (in Column L) should be visible after entering anything in Column A.

I understood that you wanted to refresh the basic filter of the column "L" when the column "A" is edited. From your question, I had thought that you wanted to refresh the basic filter of the column "L" when the column "L" is edited. But I understood that my understanding was not correct.

When you want to refresh the basic filter of the column "L" when the column "A" is edited, how about the following sample script?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 1) return;
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  const fRange = filter.getRange();
  const criterion = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(12).copy();
  filter.remove();
  fRange.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(12, criterion);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm definitely filing this one away for future use. 

I do realize that I was a little fast-and-loose with the word filter. Rather than a filter created as a result of a formula, I need to refresh a Filter View, i.e. one created by selecting the funnel and setting up a Filter by condition...

An example of what I have can be viewed here: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Db9ZNKTlLzM4nm8iIodfJ20twNvtEWxUKquu2TRuaM/edit?usp=sharing)

Essentially nothing above the #5 (in Column L) should be visible after entering anything in Column A.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I understood that you wanted to refresh the basic filter of the column "L" when the column "A" is edited. From your question, I had thought that you wanted to refresh the basic filter of the column "L" when the column "L" is edited. But I understood that my understanding was not correct. I apologize for my poor English skill. For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Fantastic! This works perfectly. Thank you for your attention and for the comprehensive response.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.