# How to refresh a filter onEdit() in Google sheets when editing a different sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a custom data filter to refresh when editing a cell. However the answers I have found such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799857/5438343 are for when you edit a cell on the same sheet as the filter. However, in my case I wish to force the filter to refresh when I edit a cell on a different sheet, and can't quite work out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUGGESTION:

The simple **onEdit** trigger `onedit(e)` cannot run with authorization, thus it is not applicable to your goal in accessing/editing a separate Spreadsheet file via Apps Script. Perhaps you can structure your function this way by using an [**onEdit**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) installable trigger & the [**openByUrl()**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl) method:

[***Updated***]

### Sample script derived from [Refresh a filter onEdit() in Google sheets when number is less than x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799857/15384825)

```
function refreshTheOtherSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("THE_OTHER_SPREADSHEET_URL").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  const fRange = filter.getRange();
  const criterion = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(2).copy(); //e.g. filter is on column B or column #2
  filter.remove();
  fRange.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criterion);
}
```

### Steps

1. Add the the script above to the Spreadsheet where you'll be editting a cell.
2. Run the script once from the Apps Script editor to be able to accept
   the authorization.
3. Follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) on how to manually create an **onEdit** installable trigger for the script function.
4. On the `Add Trigger screen`, choose the function to run (e.g. `refreshTheOtherSheet`)

> [image]

5. Select `On edit` as the event type & save.

### Sample Demonstration

- The test `Other sheet`

> [image]

- The test `Main sheet`, where I have added the installable trigger & script

> [image]

- On my script function, I have added a line to make sure **onEdit** installable trigger works on line `10` (*it will add a simple timestamp on cell `C1` to indicate that it works*):

> [image]

- Say I have edited the cell `A1` on my `Main sheet`:

> [image]

- The `Other sheet` gets refreshed:

> [image]

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: filter.getColumnFilterCriteria is not a function

Comment: Did you use the exact script from my sample (except for the other spreadsheet URL & column index number)? Or did you edit some part of the script? I can't replicate the error that you're experiencing on my end. I have updated my answer as well for more details how it works with a sample demonstration.

Comment: if I use your exact script with my URL I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null` error.

Comment: it seems `const filter = sheet.getFilter();` is returning null even though there is a filter on the sheet.

Comment: I see, can you share how did you configure your filter? Was it something like this https://imgur.com/a/1t2VG03 ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ttEshhs.png

Comment: Honestly that's a weird behavior given there's already an existing filter on your **"Other sheet"**. Just for troubleshooting, will it be possible if you can try manually removing and re-adding your filter on your spreadsheet, then try running the script again?

Comment: Deleted all filter views, made a new filter view for starting with "S", same script error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241501/discussion-between-irvin-jay-g-and-baconcatbug).